# What is the logic behind restricting the size of an element if there is enough empty place?

Tags: modal, size

[image]

This is screen-shot of a Freshdesk's custom app. The app  is located in an iframe. Though there is a lot of free space both horizontally and vertically, the iframe has a [**maximum height of 700px**](https://developers.freshdesk.com/v2/docs/instance-api/) and that much width as in the screen-shot. You need to scroll should you have a large content.

The iframe and its parent are cross origin, and you have no control over the iframe's parent. This makes it very difficult to change the size of it if not impossible.

Now, I really want to know what is the logic behind this UI design.

#### Update

iframe has almost the same height as the from. And the rest is free space.

---

Src of img: https://developers.freshdesk.com/v2/docs/interface-api/

Comment: What UI are you referring to exactly? The iframe or the form within it?

Comment: @staccato I am referring to iframe, not the form. Udpdated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to ask the author, what was the idea behind this limitation.

Two reasons come into my mind:

- the limitation comes from the times when 1024x768 resolution displays were popular and the author wanted to make sure that the app dialog will always fit the screen
- the limitation takes the human field of focus / spot of interest into consideration - we humans cannot focus (observe with the same level of attention) on the whole screen at a time. Thus, if the app is meant for some rapid interaction (such as short input form, as in the presented example) there isn't the need for larger window.

It can also be the developers pragmatic choice, like "let's fix it at 700px and see later if it needs to be changed" but that *later* never came.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Mike's rationale,

- A small width and height discourage writing lots of text in the
  fields.
- Shorter line widths make text much easier to read and digest. Constraining the width almost always constrains height in some way.
- From a code perspective, fluid width/height iFrames are really complicated. This is being used outside the developer's control, so they could be designing if for the lowest expected resolution.